# install wifi drivers for ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, wireless, networking, drivers, realtek

I need some help to configure my wireless network. I've downloaded Ubuntu 14.04.1 and installed it using a live CD and every thing is working great but the wifi connection starts at 72 mbps and then goes down to 7 mbps until I restart my wireless adapter again. I have a usb on my Dell Optiplex GX280 in which Ubuntu 14.04.1  is installed I've found a driver for my Realtek 802.11n wlan wireless adapter but I am afraid whether it is the right one. I have the CD that came with the Realtek adapter but I dont know how to install it on my Ubuntu desktop. I went to the wireless help menu but it does not show how to install drivers from a cd or I am not looking in the right spot. I am new to Ubuntu but I can open a terminal :) and follow directions. the CD which came along with the wireless adapter also has Linux compatible drivers

Comment: can you say in which format is the driver available in CD

Comment: if you are not a frequent english user you can translate any other language you use often into english using google translate https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&sqi=2&ved=0CCoQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Ftranslate.google.co.in%2F&ei=PWjaU9zOB5GzuAT8wIBA&usg=AFQjCNEUIpeq5wyR_DgXkjN5GpyNBlvfPw&sig2=tWEb5ezdRxG2uScN7tLzaA&bvm=bv.72185853,d.c2E